# Can stormpath access token be deleted without knowing the secret api key?

Tags: stormpath

I am able to delete stormpath user access token(using access token href) using "rest client" without passing in authorization header, is this intended behaviour?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you're doing? What library are you using? What does your code look like? What REST client are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for asking this one. Seems like my rest client was caching the authentication headers, stormpath seems to be working as intended.